# Scheduled tasks (cronjobs) how to do that on one server only

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks

I have a PHP solution where a number of tasks run every minute with cronjobs (wget URL's on server).

That is all fine, but I would like to be able to launch multiple instances behind a load balancer of the same server (AWS Instance Template), and I need a way to make sure that only one server runs the cronjobs, no matter if more instances are launched.

Is there a way to "nominate" one as main server (only one runs the cronjobs) and still only use one single Instance Template (Image) for launching new servers?

I have full control over the source code, so a solution in PHP is fine (prefereable).

I would like to avoid to manually have to edit/deploy crontab for a "special" server, so they could all be alike.

I don't think that a "State" in for example the database will work, since they will all be EC2 instances, and therefor the execution of the cronjobs will kick in at more or less the exact same microsecond across the servers.

Comment: The cron jobs are usually run by the server, not by the code, if you do it properly (run the scripts via /usr/bin/php, not wget). Therefore you only need to set it up on one server

Comment: @aynber why is it more proper to use CLI not wget (asking for clarity). ?
I don't see how it would solve the problem either, it would still make one server "special" and require either manual intervention or two different images.?

Comment: wget would create a web request, meaning that it would hit whichever server the load balancer sent it to. Using CLI means that the script would only run on the server running the cron job. I'm not all that familiar with creating servers off images on EC2, but I would suggest creating the image for duplication, then setting up the cron job on the main server. That way the image would not have the cron settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this: https://github.com/incapption/LoadBalancedCronTask

It distributes your cron jobs around the nodes and lets you run local jobs as well

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.